# GraphQL different result, if different permissions

Tags: graphql, rules

Imagine there are two clients:

- Client-A has a lot of permissions
- Client-B has few permissions

Both clients send the same request to a GraphQL service.

Both get results.

Should both results be the same, or is it all right that both clients get different results.

With other words: If client-A receives 100 results and client-B receives 30 results, does this violate the spec or the best practice?

I asked what the "big brother" of GraphQL (SQL) does here: [Same query, different result (depending on user's permissions)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253376/same-query-different-result-depending-on-users-permissions)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need multiple times, and I simply return different results to clients.

Different in this case means that client B receives some list of elements filtered according to the permissions, while client with full permissions receives non-filtered list.

I don't see anything wrong with this approach. If you blocked the request entirely for client B - that would be wrong in my opinion, there are some results he can see after all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem by definition. It looks like client-A has privileges to see 70 additional results in comparison to client-B.